# calling a statefulset internally from another pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

If I have stateful set A ( 2 pods) running in my cluster and I want to call this stateful set internally from another pod, Should I call using it using the headless service or the Cluster IP service?

Taking an example of Postgres stateful set and I want to write data from another pod

Thanks

Comment: You want to connect to the clusterIP service.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?